# socket.io-client.java Error while handshaking

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to write a JavaScript server running on node.js using Socket.io that communicates with the client which is written in JAVA.

I have no problem with the server side because I try it with a JavaScript client, so I assumed that the problem came from my java client.

I have this error on my client side :

```
io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
at io.socket.IOConnection.access$600(IOConnection.java:39)
at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for 
URL: http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown 
Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown 
Source)
at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
```

This is my code :

```js
public class BasicExample implements IOCallback {
    private SocketIO socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new BasicExample();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BasicExample() throws Exception {
        socket = new SocketIO();
        socket.connect("http://localhost:8000", this);

        // Sends a string to the server.
        socket.send("Hello Server");

        // Emits an event to the server.
        socket.emit("event", "ILYES");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's should be `socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8000");` and `socket.connect();`

Comment: i tryed that, and the same problem presist

Comment: What's your SocketIO lib you using?

Comment: Please try to change your `http://localhost:8000` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` or `http://your-socketio-server-ip:8000/` with last slash char `/`

Comment: i am using socketio.jar that i get it from https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client